# Notice: Undefined variable: Team

Tags: php, sql

Now before we begin let me inform you all that this is just a school assignment and that I am not overly an expert in php and sql coding.

I have the problem, whenever I execute the script, I receive the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Team in
>   `C:\xampp\htdocs\NFL\searchmatches.php on line 30.`

From my understanding, there would be a spelling error in the link up between the script and the form file, but I can't seem to find the problem.

This is a file to search the database:
Script:

```
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","0gd1d0wgpg") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("NFL") or die(mysql_error());
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matches where Team ='$Team'") or die(mysql_error());
    $numfields = mysql_num_fields($query);
    print("<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n");
    for ($i=0; $i<$numfields; $i++) {
      printf("<th>%s</th>\n", mysql_field_name($query,$i));
    }
    print("</tr>\n");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
      print("<tr>\n");
      for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($row); $i++) {
         printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $row[$i]);
      }
      print("</tr>\n");
    }
    print("</table>\n");
    ?>
```

Form:

```
<form name="addmatch" method="post" action="searchmatches.php">
Search for the match history of a particular team here.<br>
<br>
Team Name: <input type="text" name="Team_Name" value="Team Name">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Yes there is more coding in the actual files but I figured that, the PHP would be all you needed to help me.

So could somebody please tell me how rid of this error and make the search work.

Comment: because in your sql query $Team is not defined, what is the value that is hold by $Team variable?

Comment: from your statement here `$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matches where Team ='$Team'") or die(mysql_error());` where does `$Team` came from?

Comment: team is a column name from my database so I'm comparing the textbox data to the value in the column.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses a special "super global" to give you access to submitted form values. The $_POST superglobal is an array with keys that match the name attribute of the form elements (when the form is submitted with the "post" method). Add this line:

```
$Team = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Team_Name']);
```

above the use of $Team in the query.

To recap, the 'Team_Name' identifier comes from your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Team_Name" value="Team Name">
```

and then when the form is submitted, whatever you put in that form control is available at `$_POST['Team_Name']`. I passed the value through the "escape" function so to protect your query from going bonkers (or worse) if that value happened to contain special characters.

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept answers on StackOverflow; makes everyone happy!